# Accessing multiple mysql databases in parallel

Tags: c#, mysql, threadpool

My question is all about. Is it possible to connect to different mysql databases at a time and access the database in parallel? I use C# to code it.
If so please guide me through as where i can learn doing it.. I've searched around for it all day but i couldn't get any real solution.

Comment: Sure it's possible. Just create multiple connections and use them.

Comment: I want it to be used in parallel do you have solution for it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Open one connection, do stuff in it, then open another, do stuff in that... what's the difficulty?

Comment: Ya that's correct I can do that sequentially but how is it doing in parallel... both the connection should read the data at the same time from different databases.